# SQL Query Optimization with SubQueries

Tags: sql

Could someone please help me optimize/rewrite this query?  I think I have violated a few dos and dont's in this one.

```
SELECT
    p.PropertyTagNumber, 
    Last_Inv_Hist.Plant, 
    Last_Inv_Hist.Location,
    (
        SELECT     TOP (1) comment_txt
        FROM          Comment
        WHERE      (property_id = p.ID)
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS Remarks

FROM    Property AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT     i.ID, i.PropertyID,  i.Location, pl.Plant
    FROM InventoryHistory AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Plants AS pl ON i.PlantID = pl.ID
    WHERE   (i.ID = (   SELECT     TOP (1) ID AS max_id
                FROM          InventoryHistory
                WHERE      (PropertyID = i.PropertyID)
                ORDER BY InventoryDate DESC
            )
        )
) AS Last_Inv_Hist 
    ON p.ID = Last_Inv_Hist.PropertyID
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: this likely belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```
WITH inv AS
(
   SELECT ID, PropertyID,  Location, pl.Plant,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY InventoryDate DESC) as DateOrder
   FROM InventoryHistory
), MaxInv AS
( SELECT ID, PropertyID,  Location, Plant
  FROM inv 
  WHERE DateOrder = 1
), MaxComment AS
(
  SELECT comment_txt, property_id
  FROM (
    SELECT comment_txt, property_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY property_id ORDER BY ID DESC) AS IdOrder
    FROM   Comment
  ) X
  WHERE IdOrder = 1
)
SELECT
  p.PropertyTagNumber, 
  MaxInv.Plant, 
  MaxInv.Location,
  MaxComment.Comment_txt
FROM Property AS p 
LEFT JOIN MaxComment On p.ID = MaxComment.propertyID
LEFT JOIN MaxInv ON ON p.ID = MaxInv.PropertyID
```

Some notes --

- By putting the code that finds the max values for a given column in a CTE (or you could use a sub-query, I just think CTE is easier to read) you only do one select -- in your code you are doing a select for every row (unless your product is smart enough to optimize.)
- I show you two ways to do the CTE on purpose -- some might like one way over another.
- I find the comment choice very strange -- why use ID to decide which one to show?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the composite table.  Just learning now that it is similar to temp table.  I was thinking of using temp table to store some of the subqueries but was not sure it buys me anything.

Comment: These are called CTEs -- Common Table Expressions.  Common in this case means shared.  You should probably use CTEs instead of temp tables when you can, in general the performance will be better because the compiler/server can optimize how to store them based on a number of factors.